# Is Hitchen’s razor self refuting?

Tags: occams-razor

[Hitchen’s razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitchens%27s_razor) states that which can be asserted without evidence can be dismissed without evidence. But if something is dismissed without evidence, aren’t you asserting that it isn’t true? But if you’re asserting that it isn’t true, then you’re now asserting something without evidence, leading to a contradiction.

Comment: Dismissal is neither assertion nor denial, it is declining to consider for whatever reason or without any.

Comment: Negating, rejecting, or being unconcerned with, an assertion are not necessarily all the same thing; see [the SEP article on negation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/negation/#NegRejDen) and discussion of "neg-raising": "The 'neg-raised' reading of *I don’t think that p* as 'I think that not-p' has often been deplored by grammarians or philosophers as an illogical placement of negation, an unfortunate ambiguity..."

Comment: Arguably, by talking about evidence, Hitchens is implicitly speaking of empirical claims only. If so, then since he is proposing an a priori principle, his principle would not even apply to itself, much less defeat itself. A terminology note: this sort of statement would be considered self-defeating, not self-refuting. That is, although it might be considered paradoxical in some sense, it is not self-contradictory.

Comment: I consider hitchens' razor to be *self-sharpening*.

Comment: And the Good Question Award goes to **thinkingman**.  Made me look! Just what the doc ordered the last time I met him.

Answer (score 1):

Dissmissal is an assertion, but an assertion about yourself.

By dissmissing claim A you are claiming "I do not hold A to be true". This says nothing about claim A, but expresses a claim about your own state of mind. "I do not think aliens come to visit Earth" is true wether or not aliens do indeed come to visit Earth.

You still could be required to provide evidence about the thoughts you are having, but those are by nature difficult to provide. For example you can show your behavior is in accordance with what you hold to be true (have an investment in this company you claim has lot's of potential, etc).

In any case if you just say "I don't think aliens come to visit Earth" without providing evidence for this thought I can still dissmiss this by saying i don't believe you. There is no contradiction here.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a Bayesian interpretation to it. From this interpretation it only makes sense in regard to certain kinds of assertions. If you assert that some complex object exists or some complex event happened - without evidence - then the prior probability of that being true is very low because of Occam's razor, and gets exponentially lower the more complex the object or event is. So, without a commensurate amount of evidence, the posterior probability is also very low, so the complex object very likely does not exist, and that is why we would dismiss the claim.

In this interpretation, Hitchen's razor isn't self-refuting in the way you suggest, because the *negation* of a claim that a complex object exists is a different kind of claim, not the kind of claim to which the razor is meant to apply. The claim (without evidence) that a complex object doesn't exist has a very high prior probability.

To get a little more intuition about why these probabilities are high or low, we can consider a claim that a complex object exists as a conjunction of conditions. And with each condition in the conjunction, the prior probability gets lower. "There is a man across the street wearing a broad-brimmed hat and a t-shirt, walking his Pomeranian," decomposes to "There is a person across the street AND the person is male AND the person is an adult AND the person is wearing a hat AND the hat has a brim AND the brim is broad AND the person is wearing a shirt AND the shirt is a t-shirt AND the person is walking a dog AND the dog is a Pomeranian." With every additional term in this conjunction the probability gets exponentially lower and lower, because P(A ∧ B) <= P(A) for any B, and if A and B are independent, P(A ∧ B) = P(A) P(B), so the probabilities multiply, the more complicated the object is.

Answer (score 0):

No. Think of it another way- any assertions made without evidence are only as valid as their counter assertions. You assert god exists. I can just as well assert god doesn't. If you don't feel the need to justify your assertion, I don't have to justify the fact that  I think it's bonkers.

Answer (score 0):

Asking for some support, justification or evidence for a claim is a very low bar. Otherwise, someone could assert A, someone else could assert not-A, and there would be no reason to prefer one over the other. There would be no progress towards a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways that it could be interpreted:

1. If someone asserts P without any supporting evidence, you need no better reason than that to dismiss their assertion of P, leaving you where you started: as though they'd said nothing.
2. If someone asserts P without any supporting evidence, they might as well have asserted ¬P without any supporting evidence. That means they're inconsistent (not you, who is using the razor against them): they ought to believe ¬P as well as P.

My impression from reading Hitchens's original use of the phrase (which can be found in a footnote to the Wikipedia article) is that he intended the first interpretation.